# Hikari Connection Pool - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp

I am trying to create Hikari connection pool with Postgres database.
Hikari version is 3.4.1 and postgres driver version is 42.2.5

My connection properties are as follows.

mdb.hcp.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

mdb.hcp.username=user1

mdb.hcp.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2001/db1?ssl=false

mdb.hcp.password=pass

mdb.hcp.maximumPoolSize=1

mdb.contractSchema=schema1

I am getting below exception.

06-12-2019 17:40:08.181 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase    - HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getNetworkTimeout() is not yet implemented.)
06-12-2019 17:40:08.649 [main] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase    - HikariPool-1 - Default transaction isolation level detection failed (This ResultSet is closed.).
06-12-2019 17:40:08.656 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool    - HikariPool-1 - Error thrown while acquiring connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1875)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:37)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:221)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1853)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:382)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:904)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDefaultIsolation(PoolBase.java:471)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:434)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:402)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:355)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Try to switch to a newer postgres driver version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql